# Remove original timestamps from questions and answers

Tags: discussion, questions, timestamps

This is a radical idea, I'm not sure what I think of it myself, but I'll throw it out here anyway:

Remove the original posting timestamp, **only show the last edit timestamp**.

The purpose is emphasize and support the idea that SO is not a collection of historical data, but a living repository of up-to-date knowledge. Time of original posting is historical information, which shouldn't really matter, assuming edits were used to bring the content up-to-date when they happened, and assuming question includes all relevant information like software versions and right tags.

Possible implementation: For answers, show time of last edit (following roll-backs to actual version). For the question, show latest time the question or its answers were edited. Only show actual timestamps of each revision in the revision history.

Some questions, as basis for answering this:

- Would other technical (code or presentation) changes be needed?
- Would some guideline changes be needed, would the SO participants need to act or think differently?
- How might this change the dynamics of SO?

Special point of interest:

- How would this change duplicate handling?

Comment: @DCShannon Thanks, but it's ok. Here at meta downvote can also mean "I think this is a terrible idea", voting is a bit different than at the main site. The rep isn't gained/lost here anyway, so even compassionate people can feel free to upvote or downvote based on the issue only.

Comment: Well that seems odd. No reason we can't vote on the questions the same, and then upvote the answer that says that the idea is bad, but alright.

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah, the voting system is really built for the actual main QA sites, and meta sites just use the same system even if it isn't a very good fit here (in my opinion, anyway).

Answer (score 14):

**No**

I disagree with this idea:

I'd like to know if a answer I'm looking at when searching for an issue was written in 2008 or just last week.

Among other reasons, using up-to-date methods can often save processing power, or reduce security risks, in programming related issues.

I like the idea of a *"living repository of up-to-date knowledge"*, but people don't generally update answers they wrote a year ago.

**Edit:**

You *could* manually hide the field by adding the following css to some kind of userstyles plugin, for SO:

```
.user-action-time{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Well, the time shown would be time of last edit, so as long as frivolous edits could be avoided, there'd be no problem.

Comment: Not everyone edits their answers. I really don't see the added value of removing the "Posted" timestamp.

Comment: Also, I'd like to note that this doesn't really answer any of the specific questions, except maybe "How might this change dynamics of SO?" by saying it'd make it harder to find up-to-date information.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I don't see the point of speculating what would need to change on SO if a idea like this gets implemented.

Comment: Also, a question could be relating to an older version of an API.

Answer (score 3):

> Time of original posting is historical information, which shouldn't really matter,

At least **for reasons of moderation**, the times at which posts are made *does* matter:

1. All else being equal if two questions are duplicate of one another, the newer one should be closed as duplicate of the older one. (Generally, we want to close as duplicate the question which, together with its answers, is of lesser quality, but I've said "all else being equal".)
2. Answers that duplicate an earlier answer are generally worthy of deletion. ("Duplicate" is more complicated than the word suggests but the details are not important in the context of *this* question.) However, there need to be "enough time" between the earlier answer and the later answer to make deletion a valid option. We don't penalize people who happen to post what is essentially the same solution at about the same time. This often happens when a question is just posted and can be easily answered. It could also happen later if a question is given a bounty or is publicized through a link. We need the time stamps to know whether there is a case to be made.
3. Plagiarism, for essentially the same reasons as the previous point but this can happen across questions. (Duplicate answers are not necessarily cases of plagiarism, and a case of plagiarism is not necessarily a duplicate answer.)
4. General disputes about who did what when.

This is just off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm not suggesting revision history to be hidden. I'd even claim that currently, revision history must be checked for all of these to see what really happened (if post shows it was edited).